# Show this text only when customer fills in new address in checkout

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, drop-downs

*** Indicates required field.**

I want this text to be shown only when customer fills in new address form in one page checkout.

Otherwise if customer chooses address from dropdown this text should be hidden.

Can someone pls help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your onepage checkout billing and shipping template files

```
<?php if (!$this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
   * Indicates required field.
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am sure these templates already uses this function **customerHasAddresses()**    to show the new address form or the existing addresses in a dropdown.

Comment: I need this text to be shown only when the form is filled and not when the select box is shown. :(

Comment: Can u pls tel me someone condition instead of customerHasAddresses because even if a customer already has an address they can add new address.

Comment: Just edited my answer its supposed to be                                           if (!$this->customerHasAddresses()):

Comment: why cant you write a script to check whether the customer selects the "add new address" option to display this message or not ?

Comment: This also doesnt work.. If customer already has saved address and if they click on add new address this text will not show. :(

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed :(

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:** If a customer is logged in and lands on checkout, the default select option will be the presaved address. If the presaved address is selected, then do not show the Required messaging. If 'New Address' is selected, then show the Required messaging.

```
<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>

    <p class="required" style="display:none;"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>

    jQuery('#billing-address-select').change(function(){

    // All saved addresses have a value, whereas New Address' value is blank
      if(jQuery(this).val() == ''){ 

    // Make the Required messaging appear
        jQuery( '#co-billing-form .required' ).css( "display", "block" );

      } else

    // Make the Required messaging disappear
        jQuery( '#co-billing-form .required' ).css( "display", "none" );

    });

<?php else: ?>

    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note:** The above has been designed to only work on the Billing Address portion. In order to make this work with the shipping address section as well, duplicate it and swap `#co-billing-form` for `#co-shipping-form` and `#billing-address-select` with `#shipping-address-select`.